# Statements equivalent to convergence of a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence such that $a_n \geq 0$ $\forall n \in \mathbb N$. I am trying to decide which of the followign statements are equivalent to the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$:

[image]

I know that the partial sums converging is the definition of the series converging so that's certainly equivalent. I also know that the 3rd statement is not equivalent since $a_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$ is a counterexample. I also know that the last statement is trivially not equivalent. However I'm having difficulty in deciding which of the first two are equivalent. My intuition tells me that the first statement is not equivalent since if the partial sums are bounded then they need not necessarily converge, however I'm not sure if $a_n$ being at least zero has an effect on this. Moreover, I'm not certain if the second statement is equivalent since I know that if a sequence is Cauchy then it doesn't necessarily converge, but, again, I'm not sure if $a_n$ being at least zero has an effect on this. I know that at least one of the first two statements are certainly equivalent but I'm not sure which are.

Comment: The first statement is equivalent if $(a_n)$ are assumed to be non-negative reals. Without such assumption, you may consider examples such as $a_n=(-1)^n$. The second statement is equivalent to the convergence of the sum in $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\mathbb{C}^n$, or any complete normed space you name it.

Comment: As long as $a_n\ge 0$ for all $n$, both of the first two statements are equivalent to convergence. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_series